# SQL Scheduling System

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create an Exam Scheduling system. now my objective is to avoid the user to insert a conflict time schedule for the same room in SQL Server 2008.
for example:

for room **202** there's a schedule of

```
02/27/2017 4:00pm - 5:00pm
```

so what if the user input for room **202** is

```
02/27/2017 3:50pm - 5:10pm
```

obviously this is conflict.

if I'm going to use between obviously it will not work for the given example input.

Kindly help. 
Thanks

Comment: between _will_ work it just depends on what you're checking. 4pm _is_ between 3:50 and 5:10. Just make sure you are using the correct data types. If you have a code specific question, please post the code you've tried and what kind of database you're using (i.e. MySQL or SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Like Nick said,`between` is exactly what you need. In conjunction with `exists` or `not exists` in this case, you will be able to avoid schedule conflict.
You do the `insert` only if there is no entry in schedule for the same room, for the same day, that have a starting or ending time that is between the new time slot (which indicated a conflict).

Look at this example :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e015/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule
    ([room] int, [date] date, [start] time, [finish] time)
;

INSERT INTO schedule
    ([room], [date], [start], [finish])
SELECT  202, '2017-02-26', '16:00', '17:00'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM schedule 
                  WHERE room = '202' AND date = '2017-02-26' AND 
                   (start BETWEEN '16:00' AND '17:00'
                    OR finish BETWEEN '16:00' AND '17:00'))
;

INSERT INTO schedule
    ([room], [date], [start], [finish])
SELECT  202, '2017-02-26', '15:50', '17:10'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM schedule 
                  WHERE room = '202' AND date = '2017-02-26' AND 
                   (start BETWEEN '15:50' AND '17:10'
                    OR finish BETWEEN '15:50' AND '17:10'))
;

INSERT INTO schedule
    ([room], [date], [start], [finish])
SELECT  202, '2017-02-26', '15:00', '15:59'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM schedule 
                  WHERE room = '202' AND date = '2017-02-26' AND
                   (start BETWEEN '15:00' AND '15:59'
                    OR finish BETWEEN '15:00' AND '15:59'))
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  *
FROM schedule
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e015/1/0)**:

```
| room |       date |            start |           finish |
|------|------------|------------------|------------------|
|  202 | 2017-02-26 | 16:00:00.0000000 | 17:00:00.0000000 |
|  202 | 2017-02-26 | 15:00:00.0000000 | 15:59:00.0000000 |
```

In an application, make it look like this :

Pseudo :

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM schedule 
WHERE room = '202' AND date = '2017-02-26' AND
      (start BETWEEN '15:00' AND '15:59'
       OR finish BETWEEN '15:00' AND '15:59')

if count(*) = 0 then
     INSERT INTO schedule
       ([room], [date], [start], [finish])
     SELECT  202, '2017-02-26', '15:00', '15:59'
else
    ERROR "CONFLICT WITH ANOTHER SCHEDULE"
end if
```